# Why are bad superblocks happening

Tags: raid0, bad-blocks

I have Dell MD1000 storage that has 3x 2TB sata hdds (RAID 0, will move to RAID 6 soon) and 90% of time I am reading from it 40-60MBps via webserver. When I want to restart machine I simply stop webserver, unmount storage and when machine boots and I try to mount it I am having bad superblock issues. Twice restarted server in two days and twice had to repair bad superblock.

Where am I failing? How to prevent against this?

Comment: Is there any relevant information in the logs on either system ? I hope you have good backups too R0 and filesystem errors is a scary place to be.

Comment: Nothing interesting in the logs :/ I have no idea why this problem occurs...

Comment: Do you have bad blocks on your disk(s) and/or are the hard drives going bad?  My first step would be to get support on the phone and get an explanation from them and/or replacement disks.  Maybe my second step, actually... since they'd have me run some HD diags, I'd kick those off, then pick up the phone.  Better safe than sorry when it comes to hard drives.

Comment: Harddrives seem to be ok, all are in online state, no failure predicted, speed is good, so after I run e2fsck it is processing already 20 hours and I am getting hundreds or thousands of: Illegal block .. CLEARED and inodes corruption size/block is ... should be 0 FIXED. Does that mean I will lose all my data? I feel like I've already lost them :/